# How can i open other thread to count how much record insert into the sql server table?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm creating a Windows application in c#. I am trying to read data from a csv file and insert its data into a MS SQL server database table. 
I have written this code to read the data from the csv file:

```
int counter=0;
System.IO.StreamReader objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(1256));
do
{
    //this part read data line by line and insert into the sql server database
    counter++;//counter show line read
    //show counter value into the label

}
```

When I run this code, a label hangs up and does not show anything. I think it should open a new thread to show a counter variable in the label. How can I create a new thread?

Comment: Do the long running task in another thread, such as the background worker thread. This will keep your UI responsive. You can then handle the progress changed of the background worker, to update UI elements, since the handler executes on the thread which spawned the background worker.

Comment: thanks my friend,can you write code or sample to me?

Comment: There's a sample on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks my friend,please wait to test that